# Intersections of two exponential curves in a plane

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, dynamical-systems, plane-curves

I am struggling to show that two exponential curves in $\mathbb{R}^n$ do not overlap except finite distinct points. Could anyone help me?

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $a_x,a_y,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
Consider two curves $f,g: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R^n}$, which are defined as
$$
f(x)=e^{Ax}a_x,\quad x\in[x_m,x_M]\subset\mathbb{R},\\
g(y)=e^{Ay}a_y+b,\quad y\in[y_m,y_M]\subset\mathbb{R}.
$$
Show that

> two curves $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ do not have infinite
>   crossing points except the case that $b={\bf 0}$ and $\exists z\in\mathbb{R}$ 
>   s.t. $a_x=e^{Az}a_y$.

Or, show that

> there exists an open interval $(x_1,x_2)$, 
>   $x_m\leq x_1< x_2\leq x_M$ such that $\forall x\in(x_1,x_2)$,
>   $\exists y\in[y_m,y_M]$ and $f(x)=g(y)$ **only if** $b={\bf 0}$ and
>   $\exists z\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $a_x=e^{Az}a_y$.

Once the second statement has been shown, we can show that the first one since $x$ and $y$ are bounded.

Intuitively, the statements are true: Curves $e^{Ax}a_x$ and $e^{Ay}a_y$ do not have intersection if $a_x\neq e^{Az}a_y,\forall z\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus, $g(y)=e^{Ay}a_y+b$ may across $e^{Ax}a_x=f(x)$ at some distinct points, but might not overlap.

Comment: @AustinMohr Thank you for the comment. $z$ should be a real number and $a_x,a_y$ (and $b$) are $n$ dimensional vector. As you pointed out, my question is to show that "the two curves in $\mathbb{R}^n$ driven by real parameters $x,y$ intersect finitely-many times unless they identical."

Comment: I am interested in the case of $n\geq 2$. We may assume that $A$ is invertible (I'm not sure if that will be helpful or not...)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2579773/do-two-exponential-spirals-intersect