# Do two exponential spirals intersect?

Tags: polar-coordinates, curves, complex-dynamics, geometric-invariant, fractional-iteration

I have lists of complex points: orbit of complex point z under [quadratic function](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/q-iterations#Forward_iteration)

```
 f(z) = z*z
```

I know that lists are:

- z,  z^2, z^4, z^8, ...
- (r,t), (r^2, 2*t), ..., (r^(2^n), t*2^n)

where :

- r = abs(z) is the absolute value
- t = arg(z) is the argument

Let r> 1, then points of the orbit lay on [the exponential spirals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral).

Shape of such spiral depends on the initial point of the orbit:  z0

I thought that such spirals [do not intersect](http://www.suitcaseofdreams.net/powers_complex.htm)

> Do such curves have common points ? ( intersect)

My naive anlysis shows intersection points 
[image]

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870620/intersections-of-two-exponential-curves-in-a-plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $f(x)=x^2$.  Let two initial points be $z \neq w \in \mathbb{C}$. The orbits $f^n(z)$ and $f^m(w)$ can intersect if $m \neq n \in \mathbb{N}$.  Suppose $m = 1$ and $n = 2$, then the orbits intersect when
$$w^2 = z^4$$
which has the [solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20w%5E2%20%3D%20z%5E4)
$$z = \pm \sqrt w \\ z = \pm i \sqrt w$$

Comment: If such curves intersect is it possible to: 1.  find continous dynamical system which has the same behaviour . 2. to compute fractional iterates ?